# SQL operator `Greater than` shows inappropriate results

Tags: sql, sql-server, integer

I use this site for learning SQL [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all). After using SQL statement:

```
    SELECT * FROM Customers
    WHERE postalcode>05021;                    ------------ formatted codes
```

I received results with lines where `PostalCode` == WA1 1DP; S-958 22 and other inappropriate results (from my point of view because they are not integer). Please help me to understand which logic is used here to do this filter. Thanks.

Comment: Your postal codes are strings (as they should be).  'W' sorts after '0' in most character sets so that seems like a reasonable result.  Perhaps you want `and isnumeric(postalcode) = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Your postal codes should be stored as strings.  Hence, the comparison should be as strings:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE postalcode > '05021'
```